# How do I change a p4v workspace root to a parent folder?

Tags: root, perforce, workspace, p4v

I have a perforce workspace root set to:

D:\Perforce_windows_workspace\depot

I need my perforce workspace root set to:

D:\depot

Is this going confuse p4v? Not finding any solid examples to go off of. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the workspace root is fine, but you need to make sure to move the physical folder at the same time you change the `Root` in the workspace spec.  Perforce stores its notion of local paths **relative to the Root**, so it will indeed get confused if the definition of the root changes but the filesystem locations don't, or vice versa.

Comment: Ok, so I would move the physical folder and change the Root in the workspace spec. How do I this at the same time. Do I move all the folders in depot into Perforce_windows_workspace, and rename Perforce_windows_workspace folder to depot and then edit the p4v workspace in the application? What steps to carry this out?

Comment: Doesn't matter what order you do those two things in, just don't do anything else that touches the workspace (e.g. try to sync/submit/check out) in between.

Comment: I dragged my workspace root folder depot into D:\ and deleted Perforce_windows_workspace from D:\ drive. Then went into perforce application and right clicked on the Workspace and chose Edit Workspace. And changed my Workspace Root from D:\Perforce_windows_workspace\depot to D:\depot. I got a popup that asked 'Copy latest version of all mapped files to new root directory?'. I chose 'Copy' and it worked! Thanks so much!!